# Cloudformation Doesn't Recognize Shell Variables in UserData Scripts

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've noticed that scripts run with CloudFormation's `UserData` attribute don't recognize the EC2 instance's shell variables. For example, the template section below doesn't print any values when provisioning. Is there any way to get around this?

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub |
    #!/bin/bash
    echo HOME: $HOME
    echo USER: $USER
    echo PATH: $PATH
```

Comment: Can you look at your instances's system log (from the AWS console: select you EC2 instance -> Actions -> Instance Settings -> Get System Log) to see if there's any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the environment where [`cloud-init`](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io)'s [User-Data Script](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#user-data-script) gets executed doesn't usually contain `HOME` and `USER` variables, since the script is executed as `root` in a non-login shell.

Try the `env` command in your `UserData` to see the full list of environment variables available:

```
Description: Output shell variables.
Resources:
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-9be6f38c # amzn-ami-hvm-2016.09.1.20161221-x86_64-gp2
      InstanceType: m3.medium
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          env
```

On an Amazon Linux AMI (note that the result will depend on the AMI you're running!), I get the following output in the [Console Output](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output):

```
TERM=linux
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
RUNLEVEL=3
runlevel=3
PWD=/
LANGSH_SOURCED=1
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PREVLEVEL=N
previous=N
CONSOLETYPE=serial
SHLVL=4
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_EVENTS=runlevel
UPSTART_JOB=rc
_=/bin/env
```